# Is it possible to install Confluents open source version of Kafka Connect to work with non-confluent platform (plain open source Kafka)?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a Kafka cluster that I work with which is managed by my team and runs on Kubernetes. We want to install the Kafka connect via helm into our cluster to work with our Kafka. This Kafka we are running is NOT the confluent platform Kafka. Is there a good way to do this? I was wondering if this would work [cp-helm-charts](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/tree/master/charts/cp-kafka-connect). Will using the confluentinc Kafka connect container be compatible with my Kafka cluster that is on non-confluent platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka Connect has never been labelled as a Confluent Platform exclusive product.

The Framework is entirely Apache 2.0 Licensed and Open Source.

Similarly, "Confluent Platform Kafka" **is** just Apache Kafka

Comment: ok I understand that it's open source - my question is if I'm running a kafka that was installed from https://kafka.apache.org/downloads will it work with confluent components like confluents version of kafka connect?

Comment: And I'm saying there is no such thing as "confluent's version"... It's all the same Apache source code.